# AngularJS - How to change the color of one of a pair of buttons on button click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am dynamically creating rows of pairs of buttons from data. I found a question on stack that looked like it would solve my problem and implemented it, but when I click a particular button in a row, it activates both buttons in that row. I only want one or the other to change color when clicked. How can I get around this? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" data-ng-repeat="item in event.Events">
        <div class="form-group">                
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn form-control"
                    data-ng-class="{'btn-success': pickChosen, 'btn-default': !pickChosen}"
                    data-ng-click="pick()">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn form-control"
                    data-ng-class="{'btn-success': pickChosen, 'btn-default': !pickChosen}"
                    data-ng-click="pick()">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    .controller('dashController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.pickChosen = false;
        //....
        $scope.pick = function () {
        //non-important code
        this.pickChosen = true;
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in this case it better to make `pickChosen` to be a button index, rather then boolean and then switch button class comparing the index `pickChosen == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default'`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn form-control" data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']" data-ng-click="pickChosen = 1; makePick()">{{item.name}}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn form-control" data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 2 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']" data-ng-click="pickChosen = 2; makePick()">{{item.name}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JyoBvFOcT9sQYIJVIJyn?p=info